# How to configure logging for jars

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback

I have added seperate loggers for all my classes in logback.xml and i am controlling my loggers using that. Now i am getting some logs from the jars that the class is using. How can i turn off or control the levels for those loggers. Any suggestions ??? I cant know the exaclt location of the jars as in the log message it will appear as if it is coming from the class itself and not from JAR. Please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose You are getting some DEBUG level messages from the "com.eclipse" jar and you want to turn it off.  You can do it like this in your logback.xml file :

```
 <logger name="org.eclipse" level="INFO" />
```